# Open org link in the same window

Tags: org-mode, window

When I follow from one Org file to another via a link, the new file appears in alternative window if there is one. Is there a way to follow links staying in the same window?

For example, I use a frame with two horizontally split windows. Left is for code, right is for docs in Org format. If I follow a link in the right window, the new Org file is opened on the left side, and I do not see the buffer with a code anymore.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The behaviour for opening files is set in `org-link-frame-setup`.

By default, the behaviour for opening files is `file-find-other-window`.

The following two alternative commands will change that so that `find-file` is executed instead of `find-file-other-window`:

```el
(setf (cdr (assoc 'file org-link-frame-setup)) 'find-file)
```

```el
(setf (cdr (rassoc 'find-file-other-window org-link-frame-setup)) 'find-file)
```

Comment: That works, thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe it would be good to add that if you want the default behavior _sometimes_, you can use `C-x 4 C-o` or `C-x 5 C-o` with the cursor on a link, respectively.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```el
  (setq org-link-frame-setup
   '((vm . vm-visit-folder-other-frame)
     (vm-imap . vm-visit-imap-folder-other-frame)
     (gnus . org-gnus-no-new-news)
     (file . find-file)
     (wl . wl-other-frame)))
```

The above code was automatically generated by Emacs when I customized the variable. I merely recast it using `setq`.

Comment: please explain/reason a little your response

Comment: enough, add it to response and it's good.

Comment: In the end I also changed it via customization, but I decided to leave it where it is and do not use `setq` for it.

Comment: There is no problem with that. I use `setq` because it helps me to better organize my configurations together.