# How to open a file (from an org link) within current window?

Tags: org-mode, org-link

When I do `C-c C-o` on an org link it opens the org file in a new window. This is fine, but sometimes I'd prefer to open org files within the current window, creating a new key binding for the matter (for example `"C-c <C-return>"`).

I've tried to adapt some code I found on emacs.stackexchange, namely :

[*How to force Org-mode to open a link in another frame?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881649/how-to-force-org-mode-to-open-a-link-in-another-frame)

```
(defun zin/org-open-other-frame ()
  "Jump to bookmark in another frame. See `bookmark-jump' for more."
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-link-frame-setup (acons 'file 'find-file-other-frame org-link-frame-setup)))
    (org-open-at-point)))
```

and [*Open org link in the same window*](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/62720/open-org-link-in-the-same-window)

```
(setf (cdr (assoc 'file org-link-frame-setup)) 'find-file)
```

But my understanding of Elisp is so poor that I didn't manage to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to your init will allow you to open a link in the current window through `C-o`:

```
       (defun mda/org-open-current-window ()                                              
         "Opens file in current window."                                                  
         (interactive)                                                                    
         (let ((org-link-frame-setup (cons (cons 'file 'find-file) org-link-frame-setup)))
           (org-open-at-point)))                                                          
       (define-key global-map (kbd "C-o") #'mda/org-open-current-window)
```