# Instruct emacs not to open new window when following a link

Tags: window-splitting

I'm thinking of two specific examples, but I'm sure there are more.  Currently when I do a rg, and select one of the files, it is opened in a new window in my current frame.  Likewise if I am following code in gdb and I step into a new file -- a new window is created in the frame for the new buffer.  Eventually I have way too many, way too small windows and have to manually close them.

Let's say I have 2 windows open

```
  |--------------|------------|
  |       1      |      2     |
  |----------------------------
```

If I have gdb or rg in window one and click/step I'd like the buffer opened in window 2.

How can I tell emacs to just reuse an existing window if one exists?

Comment: What you describe is not the default behavior, Emacs will not keep splitting but reuse the window.  Please make sure you have not incorrectly modified `display-buffer-alist`, `display-buffer-fallback-action`, or any other variable that might influence `display-buffer`.  (See `C-h f display-buffer RET`.)

Comment: IOW, can you reproduce the behavior with `emacs -q`? If yes, can you reproduce it with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: I asked and answered the same question here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/69706/how-to-open-a-file-from-an-org-link-within-current-window

Comment: Not the same question I think: the OP here is not concerned with Org mode links at all (despite the title).